# How to use Apache Tattletale to analyze duplicate Jar/APIs used in class path

Tags: java, jboss, tattletale

In my project they have used more than 225+ jar files which causing memory issue, while searching on net i come to know **Apache Tattletale** will analyze and give a report of duplicate classes and  JAR/APIs used by the application (Classpath). So i have refereed following links

1) [how to use JBoss Tattletale tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664084/how-to-use-jboss-tattletale-tool)

2) [Uncover JBoss client jar list with Tattletale](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-configuration/uncover-jboss-client-jar-list-with-tattletale)

3) [Jboss official Documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/tattletale/userguide/1.2/en-US/html_single/)

but i didn't get how to execute and run the **Tattletale** Jar file and my application is not based on maven so i am not using Maven.

I have downloaded **tattletale-1.2.0.Beta2.jar** file along with **jboss-seam-2.3.0.CR1-dist** file and used following command

```
java -Xmx512m -jar tattletale.jar /Java/workspaces/mycoolprojects/projectX output-projectx
```

but getting following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/NotFoundException
        at org.jboss.tattletale.analyzers.Analyzer.getScanner(Analyzer.java:49)
        at org.jboss.tattletale.Main.execute(Main.java:608)
        at org.jboss.tattletale.Main.main(Main.java:1099)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javassist.NotFoundException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 3 more
```

More over i didn't get what is the use of **jboss-seam-2.3.0.CR1-dist** file. Meaning i can see lot of jar files and lot of code in there but i don't know how does it help to use **tattletale**.

In the official documentation they have mentioned `jboss-tattletale.properties` and how can i set/use that.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and this solution worked for me too.
(downloaded the latest javaassist jar)

Interestingly, tattletale itself suggests that the tattletale jar contains the
javaassist jar

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The below steps worked for me:

1. download jboss-javassist-javassist-rel_3_22_0_cr1-2-g6a9079a.zip from http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/
2. extract it to a location
3. go to that location and copy javassist.jar
4. go to location where your tattletale-1.2.0.Beta2.jar is present
5. paste javassist.jar here
6. open command prompt at this path
7. run command java -jar tattletale-1.2.0.Beta2.jar path_to_application_archive output_path

Answer (score 0):

I inherited an old Maven project configured to use this plugin and got the same `javassist` errors. The plugin dependencies may be adjusted as shown to make the errors stop.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jboss.tattletale</groupId>
    <artifactId>tattletale-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0.Beta2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <!-- This is the location which will be scanned for generating tattletale reports -->
        <source>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}/WEB-INF/lib</source>
        <!-- This is where the reports will be generated -->
        <destination>${project.build.directory}/site/tattletale</destination>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.27.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```